# Checkbox values fail if not selected?

Tags: css, html

I'm building this `checkbox` that it woyld only work if all 3 checkboxes are `checked` on the web. Otherwise it will fail.

I tried to set without `value` - but it doesn't work at all.

I tried to give them the same `value` as the name or field - doesn't work.

Works only if the `value` is set as `true` - but for some reason it expects it all to be `true`?

```html
<fieldset class="question-fieldset twocolinputs">
  <h2>Question #81:</h2>
  <div class="answer-single">
    <input id="2-a" name="MX3A" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" value="true">
    <label class="answer-label" for="2-a">
      Email
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-single">
    <input id="2-b" name="MX3B" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" value="true">
    <label class="answer-label" for="2-b">
      SMS
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-single">
    <input id="2-c" name="MX3C" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" value="true">
    <label class="answer-label" for="2-c">
      Llamada
      </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: How does it "fail"? What does the console say the error is?

Comment: you should provide `checked` attribute.

Comment: It looks like it works by placing it in a `<form>` see [PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/9nG4X1HbA3qgIUB3CYxy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Demo 2 is an example of radio button pairs with the value of true and false strings submitted to server.

It seems that everyone is assuming that you want the checkboxes checked by default. Although I could be mistaken, I don't interpret it that way. What I gather is that you only get a value submitted if all of your checkboxes are checked which is odd. As a test I have placed your unmodified code inside a `<form>` and added a `<input type='submit'>` button, then posted the `<form>` to a test server. It will only send the values of the checkboxes that are checked as expected.

Demo 1 - [**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/9nG4X1HbA3qgIUB3CYxy/)

Demo 1 - STACK (Does not function due to SO security measures, see [**PLUNKER** for a functioning example](http://embed.plnkr.co/9nG4X1HbA3qgIUB3CYxy/))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <form id='main' method='post' action='http://httpbin.org/post'>
    <fieldset class="question-fieldset twocolinputs">
      <h2>
        Question #81:
      </h2>
      <div class="answer-single">
        <input id="2-a" name="MX3A" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" value="true">
        <label class="answer-label" for="2-a">
                     Email
                     </label>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-single">
        <input id="2-b" name="MX3B" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" value="true">
        <label class="answer-label" for="2-b">
                     SMS
                     </label>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-single">
        <input id="2-c" name="MX3C" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" value="true">
        <label class="answer-label" for="2-c">
                     Llamada
                     </label>
        <input type='submit'>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Demo 2 - [**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/uF1Ljv2AVyqUiylhOycL/)

Demo 2 - STACK (See [**PLUNKER** for working example](http://embed.plnkr.co/uF1Ljv2AVyqUiylhOycL/))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input,
    label {
      font: inherit;
    }
    
    [type=submit] {
      float: right;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <form id='main' method='post' action='http://httpbin.org/post'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Question #82</legend>
      <p>Using radio buttons that share the same name attribute ensures that only one of them can be checked</p>
      <label>True
        <input type='radio' name='Q82' value='true'>
      </label>
      <label>False
        <input type='radio' name='Q82' value='false'>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Question #83</legend>
      <p>If you wish to set a default, use the checked attribute. ex. checked='false' (see the radio buttons below)</p>
      <label>True
        <input type='radio' name='Q83' value='true'>
      </label>
      <label>False
        <input type='radio' name='Q83' value='false' checked='true'>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type='submit'>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, yes, you're right. I'm not looking for the values to be true by default, it's just the only way it works right now. 

I'm currently testing out your edits. In meantime, I found that in W3 there is article about what might be required here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp

Comment: @Atheri The value can be any string is the gist of the article. How are you submitting this form and what do you expect ?

Comment: Hi, in my case the value that is passed can only be true or false. Form is submitted through main page html, and then processed by second page (as form action post) and then is sent to backend.

Comment: Don't know what your backend is expecting in post, typically it's a value from a form field that is referenced by the name attribute just as you see it in the Plunker. If you want to pass a value of true or false as a string you could use two radio buttons that both share the same name attribute.

Answer (score 3):

In an `<input>` of type `checkbox`, you set the `checked` property to `true`, not the `value`:

```
<input id="2-b" name="MX3B" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" checked="true">
                                                                             ▲
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="2-a" name="MX3A" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button-input" checked>
```